# Ormlite: saving objects of same class in different tables

Tags: android, ormlite

I have objects of the class `Item` that I want to persist. I have a `DatabaseHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper`, I create a table with             `TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Item.class);` and retrieve the saved Items with `getItemDao().queryForAll()` where `ItemDao`  is `private Dao<Item, Integer> itemDao;`.

So far so good. But: is there a way to have two entirely seperated tables, daos etc. for the same class? For example I want to persist a list of Items that the user liked and a list of items that the user bought, where one item could be in both 'baskets' or just in one?

What's the best way to do this in `ormlite`?